# Symmetric algebra on a graded vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $V=\oplus_{g \in G}V_g$ be a $G$-graded vector space over $\mathbb C$. Then what is the symmetric algebra on $V$ ? What is a canonical basis for the symmetric algebra on $V$ ?

When $G=\mathbb Z_2$, then $V=V_0 \oplus V_1$ is a super vector space and $Sym(V) \cong Sym(V_0) \otimes \Lambda (V_1)$.

Comment: If $W=V \otimes V \otimes \cdots \otimes V$ ($k$ copies), then $W=\oplus W_g$, where $W_g=\oplus_{g_1+g_2+\cdots +g_k=g}V_{g_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes V_{g_k}$.

Comment: Suppose we choose a basis say $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots ,x_n \}$ of $V^*$, then is there a way to write down the basis elements of $Sym(V)$ ?

Comment: Since the symmetric algebra is defined by the tensor algebra modulo the ideal generated by elements $xy-(-1)^{|x||y|}yx$, where $|x|$ and $|y|$ are the degrees of $x$ and $y$ respectively, a typical monomial looks like $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \cdots x_n^{a_n}$ but I believe the $a_i$'s satisfy some relation. Is there a better way to write the basis elements ? Thanks.